# What are these holes for in my Diamondback Sorrento?

Tags: brakes, frames, disc-brake, rear-wheel, diamondback

[image]

The holes are threaded and 20mm apart. There are identical holes on the other side where the gears are. Can I install disc brake calipers through these holes?

Comment: One way you can tell they're not disc brake mounts is that you can't use a disc brake on the gear side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are rack and fender mounts and you cannot install disc brakes with them.

I.S. mounts are 51 mm apart, and post mounts are 74 mm apart (and look totally different). For more details on these mounts, see [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/44161/what-is-the-difference-between-i-s-and-post-mount-disc-brake-mounting-standards).

Comment: Bummer, guess I need an adapter if I want to mount disc brakes. Thanks for the answer and the reference!

Comment: @watchTower - by the time you include cost of something like Braketherapy or another adapter, the cost of calipers and rotors and a disc ready wheel, you're well on the way to the price of a new low end bike with disc brakes already fitted (and certainly in the territory of something decent on the used market). Retrofitting disc brakes is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Also, note that rim brakes (e.g. V-brakes) aren't bad, especially if you don't go offroad.

Comment: Is it possible to do with these parts:
[6 Bolt Adapter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Shimano-SM-RTAD05-Centerlock-Disc-Rotor-Adaptor-6-Bolt-to-Center-Lock-Adapter/263080448195?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2649)
, [brake cable](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0050LUBZ8/_encoding=UTF8?coliid=I28P72U13XIGJZ&colid=2HUHEAD0WIO6W)
, [frame adapter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/MTB-Road-Bicycle-Disc-Brake-Bracket-Frame-Adaptor-Mounting-Holder-160mm-31-8mm/381955754199?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2649)

Comment: and [calipers/rotor](http://www.ebay.com/itm/BB7-MTB-Bike-Brakes-Disc-Mechanical-Caliper-Rear-Wheel-160mm-Rotor-New-HP/112427420760?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2649)

Comment: @watchTower - I'd strongly advise you against this. You haven't even included the most expensive part you need, a disc wheel (the hub itself is different). Not to mention that the frame may be stressed in ways it wasnt designed for, so conversions like this are at your own risk.

Comment: I see your point, I'll just save up for a disc brake-fitted bike in the future. Thanks for saving me the hassle - I see that the parts are already more than 50% the cost of the bike.

Comment: @watchTower - if you're unhappy with braking, you could try cleaning your rims + installing better rim brakes/using better pads.

Comment: Main thing is the back tire just skids a lot instead of stopping. I also noticed when the rims are dry, the brakes screech very loud, but when they're wet, the brakes are silent. I'll try rubbing alcohol to clean and change the pads if the noise persists.