# Disk brake caliber/fork compatibility

Tags: disc-brake

I bought a cheap 28" steel fork to replace a rusted 26" suspension one on an old Trek MTB for my kid. The geometry looks good, but I can't align the the disc brake caliper properly. The pads end up outside the rotor.

I have a couple of different IS-adapters but none work. To me it seems that this 160 mm rotor can't work with the fork's IS-mount. Should I consider a bigger rotor? Is there a problem with the fork, or could the cheap zoom caliber be the problem? Am I missing something?

Pictured below is what I think would be the optimal position for the caliber. I haven't found an adapter online that would position the caliper as pictured.

[image: optimal caliper position]

Comment: Are you able to provide Make/model and/or specs for the fork?

Comment: It's an M-Wave Trekking Fork 28" [bike-discount](https://www.bike-discount.de/en/m-wave-trekking-28-fork) @mattnz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a bigger rotor (180 mm) and using some cup and cone washers from old v-brakes did the trick.

I know it's not perfect, but it seems to work with my 100 kg so should be fine with my 35 kg kid.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me as if the fork was built to take a larger rotor. You might find the cheapest/simplest solution is to change the 160mm rotor for a larger one. You'll need to measure up to see how much larger.

Comment: Good overview here. https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/44161/what-is-the-difference-between-i-s-post-and-flat-mount-disc-brake-mounting-st#:~:text=With%20IS%2C%20outside%20of%20a,can%20take%20a%20140mm%20adapter. @Nathan Knutson says that 160 is the minimum front, so I take that to mean 180 could be the minimum for that fork.

Comment: @MaplePanda I think 160mm is the minimum size for a front rotor with an IS mount caliper. In this case, a larger rotor would mean that the caliper could be mounted on the existing adapter - so instead of moving the caliper in (towards the hub) with an adapter the OP can't find, I'm suggesting moving the rotor's braking surface out by using a larger diameter rotor.

Comment: @GregShailes Oh my goodness, I somehow misinterpreted the question as left-right misalignment. Total cock-up.

Answer (score 0):

Front and rear is not the same. If you get the correct adapter it is likely to work.

You seem to be testing a few different IS adapters. It would to me make sense to use a front IS to PM 160mm adapter.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  In this case the difference is between two different forks, so the rear doesn't enter into it.